# fancyhdr package without twoside

Tags: header-footer

I am relying on the following thread to help solve my problem

[can Latex recognise odd and even pages without 'twoside'](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/262928/can-latex-recognise-odd-and-even-pages-without-twoside)

Essentially, what I would like to do is something like

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}

\fancyhead[OL]{something} % print "something" on even pages
\fancyhead[EL]{something else} % print "something else" on odd pages
```

however, the "something" gets printed on every page (instead of odd pages), while the "something else" is completely ignored.

Any idea on what is happening and how to fix the issue?

Comment: Probably, something is written to both sides (like \markboth), then something else get written to both sides, erasing something.

Comment: BTW, you can have twoside and still use symmetrical margins.  OTOH, \marginpar would also alternate sides.

Comment: Right, however twoside is problematic for me, which is why I seek an alternative approach. Including an \if \else block does not appear to help either, as I just get a bunch of error messages

Comment: You can always create your own headers using everypage and tikzpagenodes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a test to the header. In the header such a test is safe:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{fancyhdr,etoolbox,lipsum}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}

\fancyhead[OL]{\ifnumodd{\value{page}}{something on odd pages}{something on even pages}} 


\begin{document}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! This works great.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `changepage` package to see if a page is odd or even.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage%[strict] % to guarantee the correct answer
  {changepage}
% 

\usepackage{fancyhdr,etoolbox,lipsum}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}

\fancyhead[OL]{\ifoddpage
  something on odd pages
\else
  something on even pages
 \fi} 


\begin{document}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```